# Calling Controller in Angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have just started learning Angular js from w3school.com.

I have a simple question about controller.

As this is my code.

```
<html>

<body>
<div ng-app="" ng-Controller="HomeController">
<p> {{person.lname}}</p>
<p>First Name = <span ng-bind="person.fname"></span></p>
<p>Enter Details</p>
<p>First Name : <input type="text" ng-model="person.fname"/></p>
<p>Last Name : <input type="text" ng-model="person.lname"/></p>
<p>Middle Name : <input type="text" ng-model="person.mname"/></p>
</div>
</body>
<script src="angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function HomeController($scope)
    {
        $scope.person={
            fname:'Amit',
            lname:'Kumar',
            mname:'Verma'
        }
    }
</script>
</html>
```

As you can see i have used `controller` for binding the values.
as soon as i change the value of `textbox` , it reflect in `p` tag.
means it called the `Homecontroller` , but it doesn't calling that controller. i have checked by setting debug point in `firbug`. It should call the `homeController`.

As i am new , so it might be a simple question.

Comment: Hint: Leave w3schools, and never go back there. Instead read the official [guide](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide). // That said; *No* the controller will not be called repeatedly. This is not how angular works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated by Yoshi, please read the [official guide](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide) for a better start. They provide [tutorials](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/index) there and then you can start looking from other sources.

To answer your question, the controller `HomeController` is not actually being called each time a change has been done to its models. Controllers provide a way to group models and functions inside a `scope`. Inside the controller, you can add functions which can be triggered in your view.

Here is a [**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/happysmiles/t7zgs3g8/2/) that shows your controller with a model and a function inside.

```
// model
$scope.person = {
    fname: 'Amit',
    lname: 'Kumar',
    mname: 'Verma'
}

// function
$scope.resetNames = function() {
    console.log('I am called!');
    $scope.person.fname = 'Amit';
    $scope.person.lname = 'Kumar';
    $scope.person.mname = 'Verma';
}
```

Good luck with your learning!

Answer (score 0):

Please read [Official AngularJS doc](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller) on controllers and how they work.

You have probably misunderstood how they work and thus expecting a different result. It is also advised to follow the Official doc guidelines and do the following:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('HomeController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.person={
        fname:'Amit',
        lname:'Kumar',
        mname:'Verma'
  }
}]);
```

Here's a working fiddle too:
http://jsfiddle.net/hpeinar/LxyL8e5k/

Comment: And where would it be a better place to follow good practices than here :) Edited my post to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0):

As of angular 1.3, global controller functions are no longer supported.

You should register your controllers in the following way:

```
app.controller('HomeController', HomeController);
```